# Replace a character in all JSON values in a dict in Notepad++ using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

My goal is to replace 1 case-sensitive character in all the values in a JSON file but not the keys.

So my thought process is like this:

1. Highlight the part I want using: `(?<=\:)(.*?)(?=\,)`
2. Search for just "R": `(?<=\:)(.*?)(.R)(?=\,)`

Step 2 should work but doesn't?

Something that replaces it with "T"

This is the input:

```
{
Hello: Rool,
MyKey1: Something
}
```

This is the expected output:

```
{
Hello: Tool,
MyKey1: Something
}
```

I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: Following your logic, `:\s*\KR` => `T`. Considering the example: `^\w+:\s*\KR` => `T`

Comment: `(.R)(?=\,)` means the `R` must be directly before a `,`.

Comment: So, what are the requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ....
Find: `(?<=: )R(.*?)(?=,)`
Replace with: `T$1`

Or without using captured group ...

Find: `(?<=: )R(?=.*?,)`
Replaced with:  `T`

Comment: More safe is to use `(?<=: )R(?=ool,)` instead of `(?<=: )R(?=.*?,)`